# Can I store custom data values on a Konva.Image() object?

Tags: image, konvajs, konva

I have a Konva layer with some creature Image objects on it. 
I would like to store custom data values (hp and time) on these objects so when I serialize the container these data values would appear in the json. How can I achieve that?

```
var creature = new Konva.Image({
image: images[creat.id],
x: creat.x,
y: creat.y,
draggable: true,
id:creat.id,
url:creat.url,
```

**hp:creat.hp,**
**time: creat.time**

```
});
```

Answer (score 2):

All plain attributes (objects, array, numbers, strings) will be serialized into JSON.

You can just add a custom attribute into the constructor:

```js
const node = new Konva.Image({
  url:creat.url,
  time: creat.time
})
```

Or you can use `setAttr` function:

```js
node.setAttr('time', someValue);
```

To read the value you can do this:

```js
const time = node.getAttr('time');
```

Just make sure that your custom attributes names do not overlap with build-it properties.